# Illegal Access error while mocking a singleton class using powermockito which extends JFrame

Tags: java, swing, unit-testing, junit4, powermock

I tried to create a mock on a singleton class using powermockito, this singleton class extends JFrame, when I specify the class name in `@PrepareForTest` it gives an exception.

The Conditon I am trying to test

```
JComponent context = GVCScreenManager.getInstance().getSelectedComponent();
    if( context instanceof GVCSerializable)
    {
       System.out.println(" third if"); //I need to go inside this if condition
       GVCSerializable ser = (GVCSerializable) context;
       GVCComponentState state = ser.getComponentState();
            //some more method calls
    }
```

Test case

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest({GVCScreenManager.class})//due to this I get illegal access exception as this class extends JFrame
class Myclass
{
        @Test
            public void testConsumeResult() {

                GVCSerializable jc=Mockito.mock(GVCSerializable.class);
                GVCScreenManager gvc=Mockito.mock(GVCScreenManager.class);

                PowerMockito.mockStatic(GVCScreenManager.class);
                Mockito.when(GVCScreenManager.getInstance()).thenReturn(gvc);
                Mockito.when(gvc.getSelectedComponent()).thenReturn((JComponent) jc);

                ResultHolder result=new AnnotationResultHolder(0);
                annotationResultConsumer.consumeResult(result);
    }
}
```

Stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class javax.swing.JFrame cannot access its superinterface javax.swing.TransferHandler$HasGetTransferHandler
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:259)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:259)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:180)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(MethodSorter.java:52)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClass.getAnnotatedMethods(TestClass.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateTestMethods(MethodValidator.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateStaticMethods(MethodValidator.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateMethodsForDefaultRunner(MethodValidator.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.validate(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:108)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:70)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:42)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit49RunnerDelegateImpl.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:149)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

include  `@PrepareForTest({TransferHandler.class,GVCScreenManager.class})` so we need to prepare for test of its `superInterface Transferhandler`